# android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES javadoc for details

Tags: java, android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.teoit.securenotes"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="10"
android:targetSdkVersion="15"
android:maxSdkVersion="15" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
android:name="com.teoit.securenotes.Smsm"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.teoit.securenotes.SMSM" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
android:name="com.teoit.securenotes.MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

The Problem Here ..

```
    <uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="10"
android:targetSdkVersion="15"
android:maxSdkVersion="15" />
```

Tip problem

> Not targeting the latest versions of Android; compatibility modes apply. Consider testing and updating this version. Consult the 
>    android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES javadoc for details.

What is The Solution ?? :(

Comment: Setting `maxSdkVersion` in Manifest file is not required, because doing that means, your won't be able to download and run your app on `API LEVEL 15+`. The other thing is you should consider setting `targetSdkVersion` always to the latest available API LEVEL.

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same problem.

The solution : Project-> Clean

Answer (score 4):

It's an Android Lint warning that tells that you should consider updating `targetSdkVersion` to the latest API level (19 as of now). It's because your target SDK level is lower than your build SDK (defined in project.properties on Eclipse/ADT-based tooling).

When you run an app with a given target SDK version on a device actually running a higher API level, the platform enables certain backward-compatibility features. Instead you should ensure that your app works correctly without these features. The comptatibility modes are listed in the [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html).

Comment: The software works properly when you add Les interface and create a new class that happens and how the solution: (

Answer (score 0):

simple, just do this

```
...
android:targetSdkVersion="$$"
../>
```

Comment: its not a problem ,, just do this  go to ... Project >>> Clean